# how to tell egit to ignore some file types

Tags: java, git, egit

In my project I have some file types (consider for ex *.xls) which I don't want it to be committed .Every Time when I commit this `*.xls` files will come in the list I need a solution so that egit ignores it

If I right click on the file and click ignore it works but I have huge list of tree files inside many folders which contains `*.xls` files

I know `.gitignore` file will ignore the files but it should be in every directory where the ignored files should be there its very huge collection of folders so is there a way to ignore only specified file types

I am using egit in eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding

```
*.xls
```

to your `.gitignore` file will do the job.